# Выполнение кода, при условии, что есть минимум N сетевых-интерфейсов!

Tags: python, windows

[Windows] Приветствую! Нужно решить следующую задачу.

Есть N строк кода, при которых идет создание документа на рабочий стол. Нужно сделать так, чтобы этот код выполнялся только при том условии, что на компьютере есть минимум N количество интерфейсов ("cmd.exe app -a")

Вот пример: Скрипт запущен на компьютере, где есть всего 1 интерфейс, а именно:

Интерфейс: 10.10.10.10

В условиях написано, что скрипт отработает только если на машине есть 2 интерфейса, то есть:

Интерфейс: 10.10.10.10

Интерфейс: 11.11.11.11

Напоминаю, что речь идет про интерфейсы используя команду arp -a (Windows, cmd)

Вот что я пока смог сделать:

```
import subprocess
import re

result = subprocess.check_output("arp -a")
search = re.search(".*\D:")
if search == 5:
    print("Hello World!")
```

Comment: Очень странный у вас шаблон поиска регулярного выражения. Мне кажется вы даже не пытались ничего

Comment: Не вижу здесь другого варианта поиска. Я новичок,поэтому могу ошибаться.

Comment: вы не "не видите другого варианта поиска". вы не понимаете, что делаете.

Comment: и почему именно arp -a? через wmic - нельзя, например?